# Android Studio base64 image to ListView

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to do listview with base64 images.
Listviews data is json-array from server and created to hashmap.

```
                    JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString("pid");
                    String createdAt = c.getString("created_at");
                    String description = c.getString("description");
                    String image = c.getString("image");

                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put("pid", id);
                    map.put("description", description);
                    map.put("image", image);
                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    productsList.add(map);
                }
```

And:

```
   protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                /*Updating parsed JSON data into ListView*/
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        listActivity.this, productsList,
                        R.layout.list_item, new String[] { "product_id",
                        "product_description", "product_image" },
                        new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.description, R.id.image });
                // updating listview
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });

    }
```

How can I make that image string converted to imageview?
I'm new with Android Studio, so I don't know if thats smart way to do that..

Above code is from: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/
If that helps.

Answer (score 0):

First what you have to do is to convert base64 to bitmap, and then you can set it on imageView.

How to decode base64 to bitMap:

```
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(encodedImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
```

How to set bitmap to imageView:

```
ImageView mImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.(your xml img id));
mImg.setImageBitmap(decodedByte );
```

Comment: How does that work with ListView? That works fine with one image, but I can't create ListViews images with that.